# How to avoid jumping of overlays

Tags: beamer

I would like to write some text underneath an equation that changes by clicking. Consider the following example

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{align*}

\only<1> {Some text on the first Slide, \\ 
that explains some things \\
and some more text}

\only<2> {Some other text on second Slide, \\ 
which is slightly shorter}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

On the second slide the equation jumps down because of the shorter text. How can you avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `overlayarea` environment to stop wobbling of text in slides. Following syntax and documentation is taken from Beamer user guide.

```
\begin{overlayarea}{⟨area width⟩}{⟨area height⟩}
⟨environment contents⟩
\end{overlayarea}
```

> Everything within the environment will be placed in a rectangular area
>   of the specified size. The area will have the same size on all slides
>   of a frame, regardless of its actual contents.

For your example the following will work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \begin{align*}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
        \end{align*}

        \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.5\textheight}
        \only<1> {Some text on the first Slide, \\ 
            that explains some things \\
            and some more text}

        \only<2> {Some other text on second Slide, \\ 
            which is slightly shorter}
        \end{overlayarea}

    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

This produces pdf where text doesn't jump around.

Comment: Or `overprint` is sometimes an easier option (but sometimes not).

Answer (score 6):

Use `\onslide` instead; it reserves the space when not visible.

```
    \onslide<1> {Some text on the first Slide, \\ 
        that explains some things \\
        and some more text}

    \onslide<2> {Some other text on second Slide, \\ 
        which is slightly shorter}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to make `<only>` command starting and ending it's text using the same vertical space (using `calc` package). Notice that this way we need a starting
`\vspace` to add some really long texts or equations too.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\newdimen\mycurrentheight
\newdimen\mymaxheight
\newdimen\myspace
\newdimen\zerodimen
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\def\keepHeight#1{
\setbox\mybox\vbox{#1}
\setlength{\mycurrentheight}{\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}
\addspace{\mycurrentheight}
\usebox{\mybox}
\vskip \myspace
}


\def\addspace#1{
\ifdim\mycurrentheight>#1
\let\mymaxheight=\mycurrentheight
\let\myspace=\zerodimen
\else
\let\myspace=\zerodimen
\advance \myspace by \mymaxheight
\advance \myspace by -\mycurrentheight
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\vspace*{-50pt}
\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{align*}

    \only<1> {\keepHeight{ Some text on the first Slide, \\ 
        that explains some things \\
        and some more text}}

    \only<2> {\keepHeight{ Some other text on second Slide, \\ 
        which is slightly shorter}}

    \only<3> {\keepHeight{Some text on the third Slide, \\ 
        that explains some things \\
        and some more text and an equation \[x=4-7\]
        using much more space than the previous.}}

    \only<4> {\keepHeight{ Some other text on fourth Slide, \\ 
        which is  shorter}}

   \only <5> {Here we don't keep the height}
\end{frame}
```

At every frame except the last one the result is perfectly "aligned vertically".

Comment: Why when Beamer provides special environments for just this problem already?

Comment: @cfr The code can be used in many environments and just thought it will be useful since it is a very often problem. I just tested @Adarsh's solution and show what you mean. I keep believing that may be be useful for some people because overlayarea will keep an empty space if we an a third `\only<3>` below. Of course we can add it before. But sure there are cases that this will be useful. (And also I didn't knew this environment :P )

Answer (score 0):

You may use a trick. Add \phantom{some text} to get the desired behaviour.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{align*}

\only<1> {Some text on the first Slide, \\ 
that explains some things \\
and some more text}

\only<2> {Some other text on second Slide, \\ 
which is slightly shorter \\
\phantom{bla}}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```